# Is there a way to report a duplicate account to moderation?

Tags: discussion

I have answered this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365417/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu

And my answer has been downvoted, and that is not a problem.

But when I have seen the comment below it, I have noticed that the OP and the answerer have quite the same name. Why not, I know that a lot of users have the same name on SO.

But when I look to the question and the answer of each user, I notice that question of first user are answered by second user...

Well it seems that it is a duplicate account that lets the user to give SO points to himself.

Do I have to **post here on Meta** or **contact a moderator** or **do nothing and delete this post** ?

The users :

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/3446207/shafiq?tab=questions&sort=newest
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265190/muhammad-shafiq?tab=answers&sort=newest

Comment: Note that were I a moderator I would not move in this specific instance. Both users share a last name, fine, but some of their patterns do not match sockpuppetting (user commented on one question instead of answering it like a sockpuppet would have, and the questioner sometimes [asks for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176797/why-we-cannot-use-nutch-with-hive-directly#comment37319425_24177515), something a sockpuppet would not do).

Comment: To be fair, the only reason he commented instead of answered was likely because the question was closed. ;)

Comment: Then again, he answered one month after the question was closed :) If it's a sockpuppet, it sure spent a lot of time in its drawer.

Comment: But it seems that one account is used to upvote his main account. For example, the question I have answered has been very quickly answered by himself. Anyway ! ;)

Comment: It's *suspicious* behaviour, but not definitely something to react to. The other account has answered far more questions than just the first account's. =)

Comment: Though, looking at the second account's previous answering history, the pattern is repeated...

Comment: Yes it is repeated, but I have alerted moderation through the "other" button on its answer. They'll chose what to do. ;)

Comment: They have chosen.